# How to debug dotnet core program terminating with uncaught exception of type PAL_SEHException

Tags: .net-core, seh, system.net.webexception

I'm testing how my dotnet core application behaves on no internet connection. The program always crash with

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type PAL_SEHException
```

I tried to find what command is triggering it but could not find it by manual trial and error.

I know it has something to do with the network connection since I don't get this crash when network is stable. I'm seeing fine responses from my external API calls (failing with `WebException`).

How can I debug this?

I'm using `dotnet core 3.0.100` and `OSX 10.14.5`

Comment: No actual solution yet, but seems more people experienced this issue. See in Github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13685#issuecomment-591611432

Comment: Issue was found out to be a bug. Its resolved and will be integrated soon